# Problem with depthimage_to_laserscan package

Tags: ros, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using depthimage_to_laserscan package. I use the command "rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan" to run the node. But It isn't printing anything to the /scan topic. Using rosnode command I see that it isn't subscribing to /camera/depth/image_raw topic. How do I make it do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125511/problem-with-depthimage_to_laserscan-package/) by [AnuZam](https://answers.ros.org/users/11566/anuzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just run with rosrun, you'll need to remap the topics. Check the wiki page for the actual names that the node subscribes/publishes: http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan

If your topic is /camera/depth/image_raw, then you'd want to run:

```
  rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=camera/depth/image_raw
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AnuZam](https://answers.ros.org/users/11566/anuzam/) on 2014-02-07**:
Thanx a lot Fergs, it works! Sorry abt noob questions

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-02-08**:
Great! Hit the check in the circle on the side of my answer to mark this as answered and closed.